# IssuesPannel ; AddEventListener isnt working (cookies problem)

Tags: javascript

```
var colors = ["green","red","rgb(133,122,200)","#f15025"];
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var color = document.querySelector(".color");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
     console.log("Hello World!");
    });
```

The console doesn't get printed, it says Issues Panel And it says I have to update SameSite = none and strict and I don't know exactly how I mean I entered chrome://flags and I enabled the SameSite= none but still the console doesn't get printed and still says the same problem which is weird so what's wrong with my AddEventListener?

Comment: if you include the above code just before the closing `</body>` body tag it will work if the button with Id `btn` exists. The sameSite origin error you see in the console is something else and has nothing to do with this button not working. (see here your javascript from above works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/nc7raLpo/)

Comment: The issue with the cookies and the reason your JS isn't working are unrelated.